# Inserting PDF or anytype of file in SQLITE database using Javafx(netbeans)

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, netbeans

I'm  creating a desktop App  where user can import file and retrieve them from database (SQlite) and them see or modify data 
So if someone can help me with all this 
   1.I created database using SQLITE 
   2.I used button for filechooser then A button save for import to database 
Problems 
   1. Open file (done) 
    2.saving into database (No)
U can see my code

**Mycode** open button

```
public void openfolder (ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
    fc.setInitialDirectory(new File("C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\sogece\\src\\PDFimport"));
    fc.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
    new ExtensionFilter("PDF Files","*.PDF"));
    List<File> selectedFiles = fc.showOpenMultipleDialog(null);
    if (selectedFiles !=null){
        for(int i =0;i <selectedFiles.size();i++){
        listview.getItems().add(selectedFiles.get(i) .getAbsolutePath());
        }}else{
        System.out.println("file is not valid");
    }}
```

**Mycode**   save button

```
String query = "INSERT INTO PDFS (liste) VALUES (" + listview.getAccessibleText()
        + ")";

System.out.println("Inserting\n" + query);
insertStatement(query);

Connection c = null;
Statement stmt = null;
try {
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:sogeclair.sqlite");
    c.setAutoCommit(false);
    System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
    stmt = c.createStatement();

    stmt.close();
    c.commit();
    c.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e.getClass().getField(query) + ": " + e.getMessage());
    System.exit(0);
}
```

**and the error**

```
Inserting
INSERT INTO PDFS (liste) VALUES (null)
Opened database successfully
Our query was: INSERT INTO PDFS (liste) VALUES (null)
Opened database successfully
Deleting directory 
C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\NetBeansProjects\sogece\dist\run674970846
```

Then I used another  solution  for Import PDF  but I got this as ERROR
**Code**

```
    String query = "INSERT INTO PDFS (liste) VALUES (?) "try (PreparedStatement stm = connection.prepareStatement(query) {
//NOTE: Position indexes start at 1, not 0
stm.setString(1, listview.getAccessibleText ());

stm.executeUpdate();
```

}

error
`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet. at sogeclair.connection.prepareStatement(connection.java:17) at sogeclair.PlanningController.btninsert(PlanningController.ja‌​va:285) ... 58.`

---

I went Back to  verify the problem but I didn't  understand what does it mean 
Connection.java :17

```
class connection { static PreparedStatement prepareStatement(String query) { throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
```

PlanningController.java:285 :`try (PreparedStatement stm = connection.prepareStatement(query))`

Comment: Please paste your code into your question, the screenshot isn't legible

Comment: @YCF_L can you help with  this and thank you :D

Comment: You are never executing the statement. What do you expect? Magic?

Comment: I executed that statement but  i Got this in return                                               
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
 at sogeclair.connection.prepareStatement(connection.java:17)
 at sogeclair.PlanningController.btninsert(PlanningController.java:285)
 ... 58 more
and i went back to  verify  but  i didn't understand where the mistake is located

Comment: (connection.java:17)  :::                                                                         class connection {

    static PreparedStatement prepareStatement(String query) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }   for           (PlanningController.ja‌​va:285)                                                                                                 
 try (PreparedStatement stm = connection.prepareStatement(query))

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO PDFS (liste) VALUES (" +listview.getAccessibleText ()+ ")";
```

To this :

```
String query = "INSERT INTO PDFS (liste) VALUES ('" +listview.getAccessibleText ()+ "')";
```

**VARCHAR type** should between two `''`

**Note**
This can cause a syntax error or SQL Injection instead you have to use PreparedStatement

```
String query = "INSERT INTO PDFS (liste) VALUES (?)";

try (PreparedStatement stm = connection.prepareStatement(query) {
    //NOTE: Position indexes start at 1, not 0
    stm.setString(1, listview.getAccessibleText ());

    stm.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: the  same  i got  this  error    ======   Inserting
INSERT INTO PDFS (liste) VALUES ('null')
Opened database successfully
Our query was: INSERT INTO PDFS (liste) VALUES ('null')
Opened database successfully

Comment: because `listview.getAccessibleText ()` is null you have to check that before @POLOSTutorials

Comment: sorry  I'm new in java :D  ,   I created and  button  Open (filechooser) then  it is showen in listeView  so i  want  to  save that using  save  button   ( .pdf) into  DB   what  should I do  :D  ;)

Comment: I executed that statement but i Got this in return Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet. at sogeclair.connection.prepareStatement(connection.java:17) at sogeclair.PlanningController.btninsert(PlanningController.ja‌​va:285) ... 58 more and i went back to verify but i didn't understand where the mistake is located    ....... I got the  error  of  connection  because  i  created a class  with that name when I copied your answer  , I don't know how to manipulate it . THANK you

Comment: You have to edit your question and post what you try to do @POLOSTutorials

Comment: Thank you for the Advice @YCF_L and I hope you Understand now what I'm  going to do